# Cannot get a checkbox

Tags: geb

I cannot get the `checkbox` selector from the [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#checkbox) working. Any idea why? `$('checkbox').size()` is always zero.

HTML page

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Geb</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="dogs" checked="true" />    
    </body>    
</html>
```

Groovy code

```
Browser.drive {
    go "file:///home/zoran/page.html"
    println $('checkbox').size() // is always zero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all checkboxes on a page using a jQuery selector you need to use:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').size()
```

Comment: This should work and is actually a css selector not a jQuery selector/extension.

Answer (score 0):

to select all checkboxes use jquery selector as

```
$('input:checkbox').size()
```

Comment: WebDriver and thus Geb supports only plain css selectors. What you're suggesting to use is a jQuery extension unsupported by WebDriver and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

simply provide id to your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPet" name="pet" value="dogs" checked="true" />
```

and then

```
$("#chkPet")
```