# How to mark html input fields of type checkbox in Geb?

Tags: groovy, geb, html-input

I fail to check two html input fields of type checkbox on a web page using Geb.

The html code of fields in question is shown below: 
`<input id="yui-gen136" style="width: 50px;" class="assemble-document" type="checkbox">`
(the other has an id="yui-gen133").

At first, I tried: `$('input[type=checkbox]').click()` 
but it didn't work ... for the two fields I want to check.

On the other hand, it did work for another input field (there are 3 such fields on this page) which in html is: `<input id="riskCheckbox" value="false" onclick="onCheckBoxClick()" type="checkbox">`

Having read Geb manual on [filling inputs and checkboxes](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#accessing_input_values) and also some discussion on Stack about checkboxes in Geb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848429/cannot-get-a-checkbox) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175809/unable-to-check-the-checkbox-in-geb), I tried such navigators:

```
$("div[id*='assoc_packageItems-cntrl-currentValueDisplay'] input")
```

which returned me two input objects I am interested in. Then, I accessed them separately with id's:

```
("div[id*='assoc_packageItems-cntrl-currentValueDisplay']").find("input[id='yui-gen136']")
```

and:

```
("div[id*='assoc_packageItems-cntrl-currentValueDisplay']").find("input[id='yui-gen133']")
```

Unfortunately applying `.value(true)`, `.value("true")` or `.value('true')`, as suggested in Geb manual and Stack discussions, on them resulted in an error:

```
TypeError: $(...).find(...).value is not a function
```

There is no Javascript code neither in these two fields nor in any surrounding element.

When, as a user, I tick these two boxes I get a message on the console "the element not found". So I followed this route and the only bizzare thing I observed is that `disabled=""` pops up in the `<input>` field for a second when I tick the box on. 
So that the `<input>` field looks like:

```
<input id="yui-gen136" style="width: 50px;" class="assemble-document" type="checkbox" disabled="">
```

Normally, there is no 'visibility' option inside  html tag I am interested in.

How should one handle such unusual checkbox in Geb? Is it a problem with "disable" option?

---

EDIT
here is the html part of the surrounding form. The problem is, all of these elements are generated randomly.

```
<div id="page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-edit_x0023_default_assoc_packageItems-cntrl-currentValueDisplay" class="current-values object-finder-list yui-dt form-element-border form-element-background-color">

<div class="yui-dt-mask" style="display: none; padding: 0em 0.5em;"></div>
<table id="yuievtautoid-0" summary="">

<colgroup></colgroup>
<thead></thead>
```

```
<tr id="yui-rec128" class="yui-dt-rec yui-dt-first yui-dt-even" style="">
    <td class="yui-dt116-col-nodeRef yui-dt-col-nodeRef yui-dt-first" headers="yui-dt116-th-nodeRef " style="width: 50px;"></td>
    <td class="yui-dt116-col-metadata yui-dt-col-metadata" headers="yui-dt116-th-metadata "></td>
    <td class="yui-dt116-col-update yui-dt-col-update" headers="yui-dt116-th-update "></td>
    <td id="yui-gen134" class="yui-dt116-col-download yui-dt-col-download" headers="yui-dt116-th-download "></td>
    <td id="yui-gen136" class="yui-dt116-col-check yui-dt-col-check yui-dt-last" headers="yui-dt116-th-check ">
        <div id="yui-gen138" class="yui-dt-liner" style="padding: 0em 0.5em;">
            <input id="yui-gen137" class="assemble-document" type="checkbox" style="width: 50px;"></input>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="yui-rec129" class="yui-dt-rec yui-dt-last yui-dt-odd" style=""></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You may need to show us more of the HTML, as "yui-gen136" smells randomly generated, and it could be that the element id changes every time it's rendered.  Showing us more of the HTML context might make it easier to select for an enveloping tag, then subselect for the input.

Comment: @BillJames you are right it is randomly generated, however for the first try I just wanted to make it going and mark checkboxes. 
I will add soon more HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When selecting by a specific attribute value, the expected value must be passed as a String. Since the entire CSS selector is also a String you should use `"` for the outer String and `'` for the inner attribute value.

To check and uncheck the checkbox use

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click()
```

To find out whether it is currently checked or not use

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").value()
```

If you are able to find a more appropriate ID around your `<input>` or a class you should consider including it into the CSS selector to avoid selecting checkboxes in other parts of the website.

In your case, since you have an id, you can use a CSS selector by id:

```
$("input#yui-gen136").click()
```

or

```
$("#yui-gen136").click()
```

======== EDIT ========

If the site uses Jquery you can open the console and see what is returned on

```
$("input[type='checkbox']")
```

If you have more than one element returned your selector might not be specific enough. You can even try it on this side, it will return only the "Community wiki" checkbox which is visible while editing a post.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click()
```

successfully selects this checkbox on stackoverflow : )

Comment: Both versions work ... anyway, this still doesn't solve the problem: boxes are unchecked.

Comment: I added a way to test your selector and a way to select by ID to my answer. Please also try with other browsers as there are sometimes browser and driver specific issues.

Comment: I already (previously) checked $("input[type='checkbox']").length in the console (on both Chrome and Firefox) and the answer is "3" so you are right that I have more than 1 element via the above selector.

This is why I tried other selectors including $("input#yui-gen136").click()  which you proposed but the problem is - none of them work.

Comment: Not quite. It's Alfresco Document Management System enterprise edition not the open source one.

Comment: Could you try removing the 'onClick' attribute for the other checkboxes where you said that it had worked and see if it still works? And finally could you try to remove CSS and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am not able to change html code.

Comment: inspect element in firefox or chrome and you should be able to edit HTML. The changes will stay until you reload the page.

Comment: "yui-gen133" smells like a randomly-generate element id, and may change every time you render the page (or any time the page is rendered slightly differently).  You may want to try selecting for a wrapping div that has a non-generated findable id first, the use .find( "input[type='checkbox']" ) to find the checkbox inside the div.

Comment: "yui-gen133" should work when using jQuery because nothing is rendered inbetween. Thus there might be some onClick behavior added via CSS which is interacting with the jQuery/Geb execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check multiple checkboxes returned by a selector then you can use Groovy's spread operator:

```
$("div[id*='assoc_packageItems-cntrl-currentValueDisplay'] input")*.value(true)
```

Comment: perhaps I didn't say so explicitly but I tried spread operator previously - with no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions guys. I finally solved the problem.

I was wrong there was no JS. Checkboxes are within a frame which was loaded with AJAX. Checkboxes were blocked until server adds a variable. One must wait for the server and then perform checkbox marking.

Now, everything works.